# Trying to get data from an odb databes in Java

Tags: java, database, odb

```
        ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery
        ("SELECT HP FROM PKMN WHERE (ID == basicnumber)");
```

That is the code I want to use, but I have a mistake I do not see...

Explanation:

I am accessing my `.odb` Database from `Java`. I want a user to Input an `ID` (saved in `int basicnumber`), add it to the query and get the value from the column `hp`, specific to the `ID`. This value has to be saved in an `int hp` and NOT prompted.

how do I get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to concatenate your `basicnumber` to the query:

```
ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery
    ("SELECT HP FROM PKMN WHERE ID = " + basicnumber);
```

then you can retrieve the result and store it into a variable:

```
int hp = rs.getInt(1);
```

See the [ResultSet API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) to explore more ways to retrieve values from the resultset.